# How to debug dying Jupyter Python3 kernel?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I'm running some code using scipy and scikits.learn on Jupyter notebook using Python 3 kernel. During the computation the kernel is being restarted with a message dialogue saying that “The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically.”. The stderr of the underlying Jupyter process just logs the fact that the kernel dies and is going to be restarted without any helpful message.
Is there any way of checking the underlying error? It might be a segfault coming from within some C++ code, but I can only guess. I searched for any relevant logs on the server and failed to find anything helpful.

Comment: Can you post any code / the error message verbatim?

Comment: This is a good question. There are dozens of SO questions describing users' environments and what they are doing when the kernel dies. But the posted answers are just guesses. How does one know for sure what is happening?

Comment: Maybe you could save the notebook as a python file and try to run it to see what happens.

Comment: Could you describe your system? Can you find a core file? I have addressed a similar problem on Linux using GDB but such an answer may be  less useful if you are are using a different Operating System. In my case, a C++ library was actually calling exit(1) when a particular file was missing.

Comment: Sorry to say that, but I cannot be sure now (or back then in the 2017 when this question about the code was posted) which piece it was that I ran back in 2016. For sure it was a script that did hierarchical clustering using scikits.learn in a multitude of variants to find clusters that would suit external constraints, but can't be sure now which piece it was. The error message was just that quoted above, not a word more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Faced the exact same issue while reading close to 5000 images as a numpy array in an 8 gigs RAM laptop, for a Machine learning project. After doing a bit of math with the resolution of my images, the size of a respective numpy array, I figured that 8 gigs of RAM is not sufficient to handle the images.
After a lot of research on the net, which involved suggestions like updating CUDA,   cuDNN, downgrading TensorFlow (they faced the same error while importing the relevant modules/packages), update numpy to the latest version and update the intel Math Kernel Version (command: "conda install -c intel mkl")(a whole day's research).
The solution that worked for me was to run the model training process on Google colab.

[image]

Now, getting back to your question:
The displayed dialogue: “The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically.” is not an "error" per se. It is more like "Jupyter Notebook helping itself" by clearing out all the variables and restarting the kernel. It is Jupyter Notebook sending an SOS signal, and getting help from itself so that it does not crash. Which otherwise would cause the restarted Jupyter Notebook to not have the unsaved changes. (Well, it autosaves, but does not "auto checkpoint")

**This "response" of Jupyter Notebook is simply because the maximum RAM capacity of your laptop is reached.** - This is the "underlying error"(response). This will deallocate the resources, enabling you to restart the program.
Recall your computer hanging when you open too many tabs of chrome? or run a program that has too many variables' values to be stored (like in my 5000 images case)? This could have been the alternative response of Jupyter Notebook when the RAM capacity is fully utilized. Hanging. Or crashing.

But instead, the developers have been kind enough to enable it to take care of itself.

Note1: Running the same code as .py script, errors will be more verbose.

Note2: If you are using CUDA, remember that Jupyter Notebook fails to deallocate CUDA resources even when the session is terminated. So this might be the reason for it to restart.

Comment: "Running the same code as .py script, errors will be more verbose" was the key part for me, led me to the [next rabbit hole](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/9678) 

Answer (score 1):

To add to the list of confirmed explanations (point 2):

1. Too much memory is required
2. Stack overflow - Too many recursive steps

In my case, when I ran it as a Python script, I got this:

> Fatal Python error: Cannot recover from stack overflow.
> ...
> Aborted (core dumped)